# How detect whether a Vim buffer has a fold?

Tags: vim, folding

I’m looking for an advice on how to programmatically detect whether the current buffer in Vim has at least one fold — regardless of whether the fold is open or closed.

I need this functionality to define an autocommand for calling `mkview` when a buffer is saved *only* if there is a fold defined in it:

```
autocmd BufWrite ?* if FoldDefined() | mkview | endif

function FoldDefined()
  ???
endfunction
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func! CurrentWindowHasFolds()
    let view = winsaveview()
    for move in ['zj', 'zk']
        sil! exec 'keepjumps norm!' move
        if foldlevel('.') > 0
            call winrestview(view)
            return 1
        endif
    endfor
    return 0
endfunc
```

Comment: Thx, "shortcut" commands 'zj' and 'zk' are definitely an optimization improvement.

Comment: @DavidUnric:  Does this function solve the problem for you?  Please, let me know.

Comment: Late to the party, but wondering if this works/is efficient... I want to put together some pieces to automatically toggle the `foldcolumn` on and off depending on whether or not there are folds. I've had difficulties with finding a function that doesn't beep my terminal when there aren't any folds. Testing suggests that this also beeps.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Try prefixing the `:execute` command that is used to attempt the `zj` and `zk` movements with the `:silent!` command—like it is shown now in the updated answer.

Comment: @ib. talk about late! I’ve actually written the plugin since then: https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami

Answer (score 0):

Based on [perreal's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9930326/477047), I did wrote one of possible solutions to my question:

```
" Detect presence of fold definition in the current buffer
function FoldDefined()
  let result = 0
  let save_cursor = getpos('.')
  call cursor(1,1)
  let scanline = line('.') 
  let lastline = line('$')

  while scanline <= lastline
    if foldlevel(scanline) > 0
      let result = 1
      break
    endif
    let scanline = scanline + 1
  endwhile

  call setpos('.', save_cursor)

  return result
endfunction
```

Comment: Note that this function is not efficient on very large files.  [The test can be implemented without scanning all lines of a buffer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9936073/254635)

Answer (score 0):

```
function! FoldDefined()
   return len(filter(range(1, line('$')), 'foldlevel(v:val)>1'))>0
endfunction
```

Comment: Note that this function does not perform well on very large files.  [The test can be implemented *without* calculating the fold level for *every* line in a buffer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9936073/254635)

Comment: Also, this implementation for some reason ignores folds of a level of one (because of `>1`), and reports that there is no folds defined in that case, which is incorrect.